# Do I need to clone props before using/mutating it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clone

Imagine a component has props and the props have nested objects and arrays. In the child component, if I need to copy to props.nestedObject or props.myArrays to state.
Is shallow copy OK?

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState(props.nestedObject)
```

Or deep copy?

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState(_.cloneDeep(props.nestedObject))
```

The reason why I am asking this is that, normally, I use cloneDeep or Immutable.js to not worry about object references. But I don't know whether React does something behind the scenes to break object reference.

PS: _.cloneDeep is a lodash function.

Comment: Depends, if just the outer reference changes and causes a re-render, everything will re-render unless child components are using memoization (React.memo etc), it's usually not necessary to get the job done but I think it's at least more "correct" and reliable to make props and items of lists new references.

Comment: Thanks. But my concern is not about performance. As you know, in javascript when you work with objects/arrays. (reference type values), you get a copy of the values before you mutate them. If you don't clone correctly (shallow or deep). It causes the mutation of original values. I don't want to make that happen when I copy react props to state without copying(shallow or deep).

Answer (score 1):

react doesn't break object reference. here is an example:

[stackblitz.com playground example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-easy-peasy-11hvhu?file=index.js)

I used Object.is() to compare the original object and the object returned from the useState() hook. As you can see, these objects are the same, so react does't apply any kind of cloning

Comment: It is interesting. Whatever we pass useState it returns the same value (reference). I did some examples in your playground example and I totally understand that, as I understand, we should always cloneDeep values before passing state or working with props. You will understand when you check the playground what I meant. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-playground-easy-peasy-1ceyqo?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an initial state for the useState hook without it being updated

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState(() => props.nestedObject)
```

That is what you were looking for